# Synaptics touchpad on Dell Inspiron stops responding sometimes

Tags: dell-inspiron, synaptics-touchpad

Sometimes for no reason that I can observe my Synaptics touchpad will stop responding to scroll the scroll function (I swipe my finger down the right side). I then have to reboot to get it back. Does anyone know how to fix this? Preferably without upgrading the driver - I upgraded the driver before and it turned out to be crap. I don't want to do that again.

I have an Inspiron 9400 with Windows XP Media Centre Edition

**Update:**

One trigger I've noticed for the touchpad to stop working is when working over Remote Desktop if the screen goes into power-saving mode.

Another is when I watch Flash (I *hate* Flash!) videos on YouTube in full-screen mode.